# unable to push values into javascript array inside object

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

As you can see in the code, i tried to dynamically create array values inside an object, it doesn’t have a problem when debugging, but when i tried to use push method in the array it throws an error.I am working on Ionic 3 with angular 4.I am calling the function on input box’s keyup.enter event.

```
// this is the object
private newsFeeds=[
{
avatarUrl:’…/assets/fb/avatar.png’,
userName:‘Karim Benzema’,
time:‘16 minutes ago’,
caption:‘Wow!!!’,
imageUrl:‘https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Ara_ararauna_Luc_Viatour.jpg’,
like:‘Like’,
numberOfLikes:2,
comments:['hello'],
isCommentEnable:false
},
{
avatarUrl:’…/assets/fb/avatar2.png’,
userName:‘Unknown Singh’,
time:‘2 hrs ago’,
caption:‘Pc:Unknown’,
imageUrl:‘https://i.pinimg.com/736x/50/e0/b6/50e0b65efd2d634053d7a8d1cd9d94fc--so-funny-funny-
stuff.jpg’,
like:‘Like’,
numberOfLikes:3,
comments:[],
isCommentEnable:false
}
];

postComment(index,value){
console.log(`${index} : ${value}`); //shows correct index and value
this.newsFeeds[index].comments.push(value); //-->error 
//Throws runtime error ‘comments.push is not a function’
}
```

My HTML code:

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]= “newsFeeds”>
<ion-card *virtualItem=“let f; let i=index”>
<span *ngIf=“f.isCommentEnable”>
<input type=“text” [(ngModel)]=“f.comments” (keyup.enter)=“postComment(this.i,item.value);” #item>
</span>
</ion-card>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Your code shows that you're using smart quotes instead of dumb quotes: is this a copy paste error, or you're indeed using smart (and invalid) quotes in your code?

Comment: That was a copy paste mistake...

Comment: @j.doe, did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your array with the appropriate type:

```
private newsFeeds : Array<any> = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me

Make sure your object is interpreted correctly. I had to replace your single quotes. You can test it by `console.log(newsFeeds);`

```
  private newsFeeds=[
    {
      avatarUrl:'…/assets/fb/avatar.png',
      userName:'Karim Benzema',
      time:'16 minutes ago',
      caption:'Wow!!!',
      imageUrl:'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Ara_ararauna_Luc_Viatour.jpg',
      like:'Like',
      numberOfLikes:2,
      comments:['hello'],
      isCommentEnable:false
  }
];
```

and make sure you're feeding it a number and string by declaring in function arguments

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.postComment(0, 'comment');
    console.log(this.newsFeeds);
  }


  postComment(index: number,value: string){
    this.newsFeeds[index].comments.push(value);



  }
```

[image]

Comment: It does not work for me....actually I am calling this function on input box keyup.enter event,I am working on Ionic 3 with angular and typescript and I am a internee developer,my task is to implement facebook style comment feature in my Ionic app...here's is the part of html code .<span *ngIf="f.isCommentEnable">
                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="f.comments" (keyup.enter)="postComment(this.i,item.value);" #item>
              </span>

Comment: @j.doe we can only help you with what you've exposed here. This is clearly an issue with your inputs your feeding, because the object and function seem to be working just fine.

Comment: My inputs were right ,I have checked them via console log before calling the push method and the value of index and value were fine but throws an error on push?here is some more html code for better understanding
      <ion-content>
      <ion-list [virtualScroll]= "newsFeeds">
          <ion-card *virtualItem="let f; let i=index">
            <span *ngIf="f.isCommentEnable">
                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="f.comments" (keyup.enter)="postComment(this.i,item.value);" #item>
              </span>
          </ion-card>
      </ion-list>
</ion-content>